# Where do the Transformers get their ammunition from?

Tags: transformers, transformers-age-of-extinction, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-dark-of-the-moon

In the *Transformers* films, Autobots have been shown to use ammunition for their weapons. In the fourth film, one of the Autobots claimed that he ran out of ammo during the battle with Galvatron and his army of transformers created by humans.

So where exactly do the Transformers get the ammo to reload their weapons? I don't think the humans make the ammo because that wouldn't explain where Decepticons who live on Earth get theirs - since the military would never work for them (the 3rd film showed that some people worked for the Decepticons, but I don't know if they had the resources).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/82669/35327

Comment: Although a duplicate, I fear that the original answers in the original question are no longer valid. Thanks to them running completely out of ammunition in the age of extinction during a battle. It looks like they have retconned the original explanation for transformers ammunition -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cartoons it is explained that they are powered by [Energon](https://transformers.wikia.com/wiki/Energon_(fuel)), which also powers thier laser AND projectile weaponry. Energon can convert energy into mass, basically nuclear fusion. And this is how they essentially change shape while transforming and pull ammo out of thin air.

In the movies, where they have been designed with more conventional weaponry, they most likely had some ammunition when they arrived on Earth and I'd imagine it's within their skills to produce it themselves.

We never see them produce any during the movies and they rarely run out, except of course to build tension as a story device. See also, (TV tropes warning) [Hollywood bottomless magazines](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BottomlessMagazines).